# Evaluate $\int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{\left(x-1\right)\cos(2x)}{x^2-4x+5}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Consider

$$f\left(z\right)=\frac{\left(z-1\right)e^{2iz}}{z^2-4z+5}$$

The poles are

$$z=2\pm i$$

$$\int _{\gamma }f(z)\,dz=2i\pi \operatorname{Res}\left(f,2+i\right)$$

$$\operatorname{Res}\left(f,2+i\right)=\lim _{z\to 2+i}\left(\frac{\left(z-1\right)e^{2iz}}{z-2+i}\right)$$

Which is $$\frac{\left(1-i\right)e^{4i}e^{-2}}{2i}$$

The integral over the half circle vanishes as $R\rightarrow +\infty$ so

$$\int _{-R}^{+R}\frac{\left(t-1\right)\left(\cos\left(2t\right)+i\sin\left(2t\right)\right)}{t^2-4t+5}\,dt=\frac{\pi \left(1+i\right)e^{4i}}{e^2}$$

Equating real and imaginary parts we finally have

$$\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(x-1\right)\cos(2x)}{x^2-4x+5}\,dx=\frac{\pi e^{4i}}{e^2}$$

That is to say

$$\frac{\pi \left(\cos(4)+i\sin(4)\right)}{e^2}$$

Here's the thing, Wolfram alpha says it's $$\frac{\pi \left(\cos(4)-\sin(4)\right)}{e^2}$$

What happened there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly equated real and imaginary parts;
$$\frac{\pi(1+i)e^{4i}}{e^2}=\frac{\pi(1+i)(\cos{(4)}+i\sin{(4)})}{e^2}=\frac{\pi(\cos{(4)}-\sin{(4)})}{e^2}+\frac{\pi(\cos{(4)}+\sin{(4)})}{e^2}i$$
so the real part is
$$\frac{\pi(\cos{(4)}-\sin{(4)})}{e^2}$$